# How to use a string in rawquery?

Tags: java, android, sql, string, sqlite

I'm creating an app on android studio.I randomly get a question using getQuestion cursor first where id = 0(will change this to something else later)

```
SQLiteDatabase myDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Questions", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
Cursor getQuestion = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT question FROM questions WHERE id = '0' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1",null);
int questionIndex = getQuestion.getColumnIndex("question");
```

In the same table there is answer column.I would like to get the answer of the question which i randomly got from getQuestion query using something like this

```
Cursor getAnswer = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT answer FROM questions WHERE question = ?");
```

I couldnt find how to use the question as a string and use it in the getAnswer query.What should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read both columns with the same query:

```
Cursor getQuestion = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT question, answer FROM ...");
int questionIndex = getQuestion.getColumnIndexOrThrow("question");
int answerIndex   = getQuestion.getColumnIndexOrThrow("answer");
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do:

```
Cursor getAnswer = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT answer FROM questions WHERE question = " + questionIndex +";");
```